# $50$% lifetime basketball free throw shooter with $5$% confidence boost if he makes a shot.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is a probability question but instead of a fixed $50$% such as a fair coin flip, the $50$% basketball free throw shooter gets a confidence boost of $5$% (from his $50$% lifetime rating) each time he makes a shot, but then returns to (or stays at) $50$% confidence level if he misses a shot or shots.  For example, for the 1st shot he has a $50$% confidence level he will make it.  If he misses it, he stays at $50$% confidence level for the 2nd shot, however if he makes the first shot, his confidence level climbs to $52.5$% for the 2nd shot.  Similarly if he makes the 2nd shot after already having made the 1st shot, his confidence level climbs another $5$% to $55$%....  If he misses multiple shots in a row, his confidence level "bottoms out" at $50$%, it never goes lower.

So for this question, I am asking what is the probability that the shooter will make exactly $5$ shots out of $10$ sequential attempts, that is, any $5$ out of $10$.

Assume the shooter makes $10$ honest attempts to make all $10$ shots.

If it helps, I calculated the probability of making $5$ out of $10$ if the shooting % was fixed at $50$% to be $10 \choose 5$ * $(\frac 1 2)^5$ * $(\frac 1 2)^5$ = $63/256$ = $24.609$%.  I am wondering how his "confidence boost" will change this "simplified" answer to a similar question.

The answer to my original question may be difficult to compute but if someone really wants a challenge, a variation of it would be as follows:

If the shooting % was fixed at $50$% confidence level, it seems the most likely outcome would be $5$ out of $10$ shots made which would be around $25$% probability.  How much of a confidence boost would be needed so that the most likely made number of shots would change to $6$ out of $10$?  Let x = the confidence boost after each made shot as a multiplier such that, (for example), if x = $4$%, then if he makes the first shot, his confidence level on the second shot would be $1.04 * 50$% = $52$% ....  Obviously x has to be a small percentage like $8$% or less otherwise his confidence level on the last shot if he makes all $9$ previous shots would exceed $100$% since $1.08 ^ 9$ = $1.999$.

Note that $10 \choose 6$ * $.57^6$ * $.43^4$ = $24.623$% so it "edges out" the $24.609$% mentioned previously for exactly $5$ out of $10$ made at a fixed $50$% confidence level so it looks like the average confidence level needs to be around $57$% to make $6$ out of $10$ to be the most likely but this is not the answer to my question it is just a hint/approximation/simplification.

Another interesting "tidbit" is $10 \choose 6$ * $.5874^6$ * $.4126^4$ = $24.99999$%

My motivation for this question and harder variation is to show that many math problems are simplified to have fixed probabilities such as fair coin flips but when a variable is introduced such as a confidence boost, the problem becomes significantly harder and very few people even attempt to answer it.  I created this question and variation and I am not even a math person but I suspect it will "stump" many "mathheads" as either unsolvable or too difficult and thus not worth it but whoever solves it correctly will likely get respected for it here on this site as well as "pave the way" for similar variable probability questions that may come "down the pike".

Math to me is like a tool such as a screwdriver but the tool should not have the requirement that the screw be perfectly straight with a perfect head cuz that is not real world.  Many screws are slightly bent and partially stripped so a good screwdriver would still work on those so similarly, math should not always (only) be applied to "perfect" scenarios like fair coin flips.

Comment: When you say a $5\%$ confidence boost, you seem to be multiplying his chance of making by $1.05$.  Then $0.525 \cdot 1.05=0.55125$  It would be easier to specify additive increases of $2.5\%$ if that is what you mean. I don't think there is an easy answer. You could calculate it in Excel rather easily as there are only $252$ ways to choose $5$ successes out of $10$

Comment: Ok what ever is easier for you.  I was just trying to avoid long decimals so I used $52.5$%, $55$%, $57.5$%,,, but you can use * $1.05$ each time if it is easier since I think the answer will be very close either way.

Comment: If the shooter makes two shots and then misses one, is his probability of making the fourth shot $50$% or $52.5$%?

Comment: Anytime the shooter misses, his confidence level returns to $50$% but never lower than $50$% no matter how many he misses in a row. This is because he is a "lifetime" $50$% freethrow shooter so he is confident he wont do worse than that in the longrun.

Comment: I'm a little "amused" by all the "quotation marks" in your "last paragraph". As for your first question, it's not that difficult to compute. There are 1024 different ways the 10 attempts can go, and one just needs to track the probability of each shot and add up the numbers. It would be quite tedious to do this by hand, but one could write a program to do it.

Comment: Glad you got some amusement out of it.  Yes a state transition table could be used since it is only $1024$ possible outcomes but I feel it is an interesting problem cuz the answer is non-obvious and there seems to be no easy way to solve this problem cuz depending on either a make or a miss, the probability changes. It seems like a probability "tree" would be needed and then somehow derive the answer from that.  This is a more "real world" problem cuz I know if I make a free throw, I feel more confident I will make the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Python/Sage program that will compute what you want. This is for the version where the increase is linear (e.g., the probability of making shot number 3 is exactly $55\%$, not $50\% * (1.05)^2=55.125\%$), but it wouldn't be too hard to modify it to do the other version instead.

```
num_shots = 10

bit_lists = [list(ZZ(n).binary().zfill(num_shots)) for n in range(0, 2 ** num_shots)]
makes_misses_lists = [[string == '1' for string in bit_list] for bit_list in bit_lists]

t = var('t')

def monomial(makes_misses_list):
    to_return = 1
    run_length = 0
    for bool in makes_misses_list:
        if bool:
            to_return *= (QQ('1/2') + t * run_length)
            run_length += 1
        else:
            to_return *= (QQ('1/2') - t * run_length)
            run_length = 0
    return to_return

def makes_n_poly(n):
    return sum(monomial(makes_misses_list) for makes_misses_list in makes_misses_lists
        if makes_misses_list.count(True) == n)
```

Now you can call `makes_n_poly(n)(t)` to find the probability that you'll make exactly $n$ shots, if making a shot increases that probability by $t$. So

```
makes_n_poly(5)(t=0)
```

returns $63/256$, the probability of making $5$ shots if there's no confidence boost.

You're interested in

```
makes_n_poly(5)(t=0.025) # 0.025 is the same as 2.5%
```

which evaluates to $0.227617657165527$: that is, the chance of making exactly $5$ shots decreases from about $24.6\%$ to about $22.7\%$ if your chances of making a shot increase by $2.5\%$ after each success.

What about your second question, how much of a confidence boost you need for $6$ shots to be more likely than $5$? You can plot the likelihood of both $5$ and $6$ shots:

```
P = plot([makes_n_poly(5), makes_n_poly(6)])
show(P, xmin = 0, xmax = QQ(0.1), ymin = 0, ymax = 0.3)
```

We stop at a confidence boost of $0.1 = 10\%$ because after that the $6$-shot version will involve probabilities larger than $1$.

The result of this plot is:[image]

As you can see, the probability of making $6$ shots *never* exceeds the probability of making $5$ (though both decrease, in favor of the probability of making more than $6$ shots).

If you plot the probability of making each number of shots from $5$ to $10$ over the range where they all make sense (up to a little over $5\%$), you'll see that none of them ever actually intersect...

```
Q = plot([makes_n_poly(5), makes_n_poly(6), makes_n_poly(7), makes_n_poly(8), makes_n_poly(9), makes_n_poly(10)])
show(Q, xmin = 0, xmax = QQ('1/18'), ymin = 0, ymax = 0.3)
```

[image: probability plot with 5 non-intersecting curves]

---

It's worth noting that statisticians have found [very little evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot-hand_fallacy) that athletes' winning streaks are meaningful, in most situations. Free throws are actually one of the few exceptions — it really does seem to be true that making a free throw makes you more likely to make subsequent free throws. But given that people in general see streaks everywhere that probably don't have any real meaning, the size of the effect for free throws is almost certainly a lot smaller than you think it is...

Comment: Wow, "A" for effort on this one but there seems there might be a discrepancy.  I have shown that if his confidence level hits $57$%, then $10 \choose 6$ * $.57^6$ * $.43^4$ exceeds $10 \choose 5$ * $.5^5$ * $.5^5$ so I would expect that if his "average" confidence level would be $57$%, then making exactly $6$ shots should be more likely than making $5$ (at a fixed $50$% confidence). Perhaps I was not clear enough in that comparison but my example of the probabilities implied it. Perhaps it is not a discrepancy since my simplified answer is an average confidence but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @David: I don't think that's inconsistent with what I found. You're not going to hit three shots in a row very often, even with a big confidence booster. Even when your confidence goes up by a lot with each shot, you'll still be making most of your shots with a probability near 50% (for this not to be true, you'd be hitting the 100% wall in some rarer circumstances).

Comment: So in general do problems of this nature require programming because they are too "messy" to do mathematically "on paper"? Also, to make this problem better, should I have chosen some different numbers and if so which should be "tweaked"? Another situation where a confidence boost seems to work is homerun derby.  How many times have you seen them "choke" the first $5$ out of $10$ at bats but then "explode" after hitting the first HR and get maybe $5$ before hitting the $10$th out? Also bowling may be streaky too for amateurs.  Getting that first strike helps boost confidence for the next shot.

Comment: In general I would say they do. It's possible that there's some clever analytic tool you could use under specific circumstances. I will note that people have looked for streakiness in the home run derby, [and not found very much of it](http://books.google.com/books?id=Vw_rfuMIxYsC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=home+run+derby+streakiness&source=bl&ots=smUc7VXvtu&sig=ArQX9PgbMdxSn2kDWNggn8p27RM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yKFWVMncDoWRyASW0oHYDA&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=home%20run%20derby%20streakiness&f=false)...

Comment: More of an "over the hump breakout" rather than a streak.  Getting the first one is what builds confidence for more.  Same with a crappy bowler getting their first strike of a game or even of the entire bowling session.